# pdflatex change my text format following after one figure, using this figure's format

Tags: graphics, floats

I have a figure between some texts. The text after the figure appears to use the figure's format. which is "centered" and "scale=0.65". As well as the following sections appeared in the same page. Can anybody please help me. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}


\section{Title}
\section{The Foundations}

\subsection{Markov Decision Processes \& Reinforcement Learning}
Some Text 1
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=90mm]{./Figures/can.eps}
\caption{A simple CAN topology.}
\label{fig:test}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
Some Text 2
\subsection{Subtitle}

Plain text.

\subsection{Another subtitle}

More plain text.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This code snippet will not produce the effect you describe.  For this reason, you should provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: Please add an image of the output you receive. Since you won't have enough reputation to do so, just include a link to the image. Someone with edit privileges will re-embed it in your post.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the replies, I have the image added. Please check.

Comment: BTW, why are you using the name `can-eps-converted-to.pdf`? The name is usually constructed by package `epstopdf` for converted images to avoid clashes with original file names.

Comment: (1) Reproducibility: Can you put the image somewhere for downloading? (2) Versions: If you put `\listfiles` at the beginning then LaTeX prints a version list at the end of the console/`.log` file output.

Comment: Hi, the version shown to me is: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.3.4)  14 AUG 2013 16:38".

Comment: And this is the link for the project BTW: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2c4s7avhg0k4eu/minimal.zip

Comment: Also I change the code back to the can.eps graph and use the package epstopdf. Well the problem still exist.

Comment: I've downloaded the file and your pdf looks fine for me. What viewer are you using?

Comment: Same here - looks as expected! I'm using gummi on Linux for this purpose.

Comment: I used adobe reader. Have you guys get the different figure in pdf file from my screenshot? I use latex.exe to generate the .div format and it works fine finally. So I guess the problem is caused by PdfLatex. And BTW can someone tell me does .div have all necessary feature as a .pdf so that I can just use latex.exe to generate my thesis? Thanks very much.